# Detect if Silverlight application being active in a browser

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'd like to know (inside my Silverlight application) when it's been on a screen and active.
So, for example I have active UI that fetches updates. I don't want to do that if user minimized browser or when user switched to another tab in a browser.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Generally I'd read "I think I know the answer" as the first sentence of a question and would just click right back out of it since it can basically be interpreted as not even making an effort, but... doesn't SL have an `IsActive` property in system.windows you could tie into?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I like to use an inactivity timer with a tick value.

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
timer.Tick += delegate
{
   IsActive = false;
};

this.MouseMove += (s, a) =>
{
   if (IsActive) return;

   if (timer.IsEnabled)
   {
      timer.Stop();
      IsActive = true;
      timer.Start();
   }
};
```